# Update Current time in every two minutes in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I have silverlight application which is having Current time and date , ia m getting this from WCF Service now i want to update Current Date and time in every minute.

How to achieve that ?

My service code is :

```
[OperationContract]
        public DateTime GetDateTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now ;  
        }
```

My xaml.cs is :

```
void Welcome_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SessionService.SLWebServiceClient client = new SessionService.SLWebServiceClient();
            client.GetDateTimeCompleted += new EventHandler<SessionService.GetDateTimeCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetDateTimeCompleted);
            client.GetDateTimeAsync(); 


        }

        void client_GetDateTimeCompleted(object sender, SessionService.GetDateTimeCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            lblDateTime.Text = e.Result.ToString();  
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a DispatcherTimer to call the WCF service every two minutes. Here's how:

```
// Every 2 minutes calls the timer_Tick handler
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0) };
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer.Start();

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SessionService.SLWebServiceClient client = new SessionService.SLWebServiceClient();
   client.GetDateTimeCompleted += new EventHandler<SessionService.GetDateTimeCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetDateTimeCompleted);
   client.GetDateTimeAsync();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Bruno